# Cannot await on async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, async-await

I am creating a Xamarin application with a shared core. In the shared core I have a connection class for socket communication:

```
public class ConstantConnection {
    public async Task Connect()
    {
        await conn.Connect (); // Calls a socket plugin to connect
        timer = new Timer (new Action<object> (ParseData), "", 100, 1, false); // starts a local timer
    }

    public async Task Disconnect()
    {
        timer.Dispose ();   // End timer
        await conn.Disconnect (); // Close socket
    }
}
```

Now I have another class, working like a constructor, that would like to use objects of the above class by executing:

```
conn = new ConstantConnection();
await conn.Connect();
```

This gives me an error in Xamarin Studio which says:

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method

As far I as I can see `Connect` is `async`. Why can't I use `await`?

Comment: What about the method where you're calling it?  Is that async?

Comment: Call this functions in constuctor ?? If yes constructor can't be asynchronous.

Comment: @user2941906 ah yes, I did! I added Wait() as Patrick Hofman described to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awaiting an `async` method can only be done in an `async` method. So you have to create a `async` method, and then `await` `Connect()`:

```
public async void SomeAsync()
{
    await conn.Connect();
}
```

Else, if you want to run that code in a synchronous method (one not having the `async` keyword), you should call `Wait` in order to wait until that method has finished:

```
conn.Connect().Wait();
```

Answer (score 4):

The error says it all. The method which has the awaiting code should also be async.

```
public async void ConnectAsync()
{
    conn = new ConstantConnection ();
    await conn.Connect ();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out, `await` can only be used within an `async` method. However, you should **not** use `async void`!

Since your calling code is a constructor, you'll have to rethink your approach. I describe a [variety of approaches on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html), of which I prefer the async factory method:

```
private MyConstructor()
{
  conn = new ConstantConnection();
}

public async Task<MyConstructor> CreateAsync()
{
  var result = new MyConstructor();
  await result.Connect();
}
```

As a side note, your task-returning methods should be named with an `Async` suffix to follow the [TAP guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx). E.g., `Connect` should be `ConnectAsync`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Stephen, async void is called "Fire and Forget", it's can bring a lot of issues to your code.

Always use:

```
public async Task<"Type"> Example()
{ 
}
```

or in "void" case use:

```
 public async Task Example()
 {
 }
```

All MVP's recomend this...